# munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer : Likely from copying a struct

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, counting-sort

The last line (the free) is returning a munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer error.

This is the code snippet (it's a first draft, so I'd ask you to excuse the rough-around-the-edges shape. It operates on a struct foo, which is a record (key-value pair) of rectypesize.

```
void csortr(foo* A, const size_t n, const int d) { // Array of foos of size n, sort by the dth char
    int count[95] = { 0 }; // Range of values guaranteed to be 95

    for (register int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        ++(count[index(A[i].key[d])]); // The index function gets the index for a char (independently tested. Correct)
    }

    for (register int i = 1; i < 95; ++i) {
        count[i] += count[i - 1];
    }

    foo* T = (foo*) malloc(n * rectypesize);
    memcpy(T, A, n * rectypesize);

    // This part is where I think the problem most likely is
    for (register int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        memcpy(&A[count[index(T[i].key[d])]], &T[i], rectypesize);
    }

    free(T);
}
```

The implementation is counting sort on a struct foo (of rectypesize). I know that munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer indicates a pointer being modified somewhere, but it isn't immediately apparent where.

This is called from within

```
void rsortr(foo* A, const size_t n) {
    // Iterate from the 'least significant' to the 'most significant' 'digit'
    for (register int i = KEYLEN - 1; i > -1; --i) {
        csortr(A, n, i);
    }
}
```

which is just a function call in main as:

```
rsortr(data, len); // data of type foo*, len a size
```

The index function is

```
short index(const char c) {
  return (short) (c - ' '); // Problem domain info: Min c = ' '; Max c = '~' => this is 0..94. Hence the 95s elsewhere
}
```

The struct `foo` is

```
typedef struct {
    char key[KEYLEN + 1]; // These sizes are not a part of the problem
    char value[VALLEN + 1];
} foo;
```

`rectypesize` is the constant `sizeof(foo)`

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows exactly how this function is called? A *simple* program that we can compile and reproduce the issue with would significantly help in finding a solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you tried sanitizing tools such as AddressSanitizer, valgrind, etc?

Comment: Using `rectypesize` as an alias of `sizeof(foo)` is not really good style IMHO - it gives the reader cause to doubt whether they really are the same.  I read this and thought "if they meant `sizeof(foo)` they would write `sizeof(foo)`, so `rectypesize` must be something else, but what is it, and why?"

Comment: @NateEldredge I completely get that, I just computed `sizeof(foo)` and stored it in a register var once because this snippet is one of many steps where the value is used.

Comment: I would suggest that, at every line in the code that indexes into an array, you print out the index first, and/or add an explicit check that it is in range.  I bet you will quickly find that one of them is not.

Comment: @WilliamEdwardson: Storing `sizeof(foo)` in a variable seems like premature optimization at best, and in practice I suspect it is a deoptimization if anything.  Compilers do better when they know that constants are constants.  Usually they can be encoded as immediates, saving you the register pressure.  Multiplication can be optimized in various ways if the compiler knows the value of the constant.  And if for some reason it really is best to cache the constant in a register, rest assured that the compiler will figure it out and take care of it.

Comment: For that matter, declaring a variable as `register` is just antique - modern compilers can optimize register allocation just fine, thank you very much, and they usually ignore the `register` keyword altogether.

Comment: But sorry, I'm distracting you - better to spend time right now on creating a [mcve] than on these side issues.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>    // This part is where I think the problem most likely is
>    for (register int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
>        memcpy(&A[count[index(T[i].key[d])]], &T[i], rectypesize);
>    }
> ```

Here you think right. Whatever you may intend by this, certainly *count[94]* down to *count[*highest key index*]* is equal to *n* as a result of the preceding `for` loop, and storing to *A[n]* is of course erroneous.

Comment: I added the index function. Index is in the inclusive range `0...94` (comes from the problem domain), so `index(T[i].key[d])` should fall within that range. Count is the prefix sum of counts of occurrences (it's a counting sort step), and the memcpy aims to copy the corresponding struct from T (a working temp) to A (at the index given by the count).

Comment: That was already clear; in the middle `for` loop cumulative sums of the `count` values are computed - before that loop, the sum of all values is _n_, and after that loop, _count[94] down to count[highest key index]_ contain the cumulative sum _n_, which is then illegally used to index `A`.